# Analytic variety

Tags: several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a convex domain in $\mathbb{C^{n}}$ , $\Delta$ be unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and f: $\Delta \rightarrow b\Omega $ be a non-constant holomorphic map.Then the convex hull of f($\Delta$) is an affine analytic variety contained in b$\Omega$.

In above statement what does "affine analytic variety" mean.